# How to convert xsl file to sef file

Tags: node.js, saxon-js

I have `xsl` file I would like to apply to some XML content in `node.js`. I found `saxon-js` and it seems to offer what I need. While I'm slightly lost in the documentation, it seems like I should first convert my `xsl` file to `.sef` file before running transform in node.

`saxon-js` readme mentiones other package, `xslt3` that should be able to do that ([see readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3)):

> Compiling a stylesheet
>
> To compile a stylesheet held in books.xsl to a SEF file in books.sef.json, to be run either in the browser or Node.js, use the command line:
>
> `xslt3 -xsl:books.xsl -export:books.sef.json -t -ns:##html5`

However, after installing `xslt3` package, there's no executable available to run the conversion.

Am I missing something? How can I convert `xsl` to `sef.json` (one time is OK, don't need to run it from server dynamically or anything)?

Comment: I get a `./node_modules/.bin/xslt3` file/command after I `yarn add xslt3` to a project.

Comment: You can try  node node_modules/xslt3.js

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, here's how you can do this programmatically, without `xslt3` (in case someone else lands here, looking for a code-based solution):

```
// xsl: path to XSLT file
// xml: path to XML file to be transformed

const saxon = require("saxon-js");
const env = saxon.getPlatform();

const doc = env.parseXmlFromString(env.readFile(xsl));
// hack: avoid error "Required cardinality of value of parameter $static-base-uri is exactly one; supplied value is empty"
doc._saxonBaseUri = "file:///";

const sef = saxon.compile(doc);

/* now you can use `sef`:
const resultStringXML = saxon.transform({
  stylesheetInternal: sef,
  sourceText: env.readFile(xml)
});
*/
```

This is somewhat of a monkey-patch (esp. the `_saxonBaseUri` part); adding it here anyway, as I couldn't (yet) find a better/formal approach in any documentation - Saxonica or otherwise.

Comment: If I could, I would give you a million upvotes. This is the first and only working example of doing a transform in nodejs that I have been able to find anywhere. Even saxon-js' own documentation doesn't contain the needed information.

Comment: This is the closest I got to a proper solution, but doesn’t seem to work currently as there is no “compile” method on the class. Do you happen to know how can this be achieved with the latest version of Saxon?

Answer (score 4):

You can either find the executable in ./node_modules/xslt3/xslt3.js after installing the package as a local dependency in your project

`npm i xslt3`

```
❯ ./node_modules/xslt3/xslt3.js
Saxon requires a stylesheet as -xsl: argument
Error FORG0001
    Cannot locate stylesheet ('/Users/<username>/Projects/saxonjs-poc/undefined')
```

or you can use the -g flag with npm to install xslt3 globally. Then xslt3 will be available as an executable anywhere on your machine

`npm i -g xslt3`

```
❯ xslt3
Saxon requires a stylesheet as -xsl: argument
Error FORG0001
    Cannot locate stylesheet ('/Users/<username>/Projects/saxonjs-poc/undefined')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [nosvalds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749075/1021892):
After `npm i -g xslt3` you can call the command to compile a stylesheet to sef in nodejs with:

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
execSync(`xslt3 -t -xsl:${xslFilepath} -export:${sefFilepath} -nogo`, {stdio: 'inherit'});
```